# Windows Task Scheduler fails at sending e-mail

Tags: email, windows-server-2008-r2, scheduled-task

The error is 2147746321.

I can see in the mailserver log that it tries, but the connection gets closed.

```
Wed 2012-10-10 15:55:25: Session 990590; child 1
Wed 2012-10-10 15:55:25: Accepting SMTP connection from [x:49161] to [y:25]
Wed 2012-10-10 15:55:25: --> 220 Mdaemon; Wed, 10 Oct 2012 15:55:25 +0200
Wed 2012-10-10 15:55:25: <-- EHLO x
Wed 2012-10-10 15:55:25: --> 250-Hello x, pleased to meet you
Wed 2012-10-10 15:55:25: --> 250-VRFY
Wed 2012-10-10 15:55:25: --> 250-EXPN
Wed 2012-10-10 15:55:25: --> 250-ETRN
Wed 2012-10-10 15:55:25: --> 250-AUTH LOGIN
Wed 2012-10-10 15:55:25: --> 250-8BITMIME
Wed 2012-10-10 15:55:25: --> 250 SIZE 20971000
Wed 2012-10-10 15:55:25: <-- AUTH LOGIN
Wed 2012-10-10 15:55:25: --> 334 VX......
Wed 2012-10-10 15:55:25: Connection closed
Wed 2012-10-10 15:55:25: SMTP session terminated (Bytes in/out: 26/212)
```

Googling does not reveal much except that it indeed "doesn't work" and Exchange pops up all over the place.

This is no Exchange server. I just want a plain and straight SMTP connection to work. How?

(I have tried running the task as normal user and as system account, no difference.)

Sending a mail manually using telnet to port 25 from that server *is* working.

(Windows 2008 R2)

Comment: What version of Windows? How are you trying to send the message? After all, it's not the Task Scheduler that's trying to send the message but whatever script or program it's running. *Relevant* details are required.

Comment: Sure, Task Scheduler sends the message. The action defined in task scheduler is to send an e-mail. I don't care how it does. It should just do it.

Comment: Sending a mail manually using telnet to port 25 from that server is working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What the hell, I am now using blat to send mails (Action -> Start Program -> blat). Forget the M$ built-in and non-working crap.

(Sorry for the frustration, but taking two days trying to send a plain mail without anyone anywhere having a clue how to make it work doesn't make me happy at all.)

Comment: The statement about anyone anywhere having a clue is not true.  We just began to troubleshoot and there is nowhere near enough detail to make an actual call if the Task Scheduler mail is broken.

I can understand being frustrated trying to make things work, but if you ask a question in a public forum, you need to understand that we don't know anything about your environment other than what you tell us in the question.  People leaving answers or comments are just trying to find the relevant details to help you.  Answers like this make people much less willing to help.

Comment: Sorry, but the net is full of people failing to send mail using Task Scheduler. Probably by "sending e-mail" they (Microsoft) understand something else than a plain old SMTP connection without gimmicks.

Comment: The net is full of people failing to get W2K8R2 Scheduled Tasks to run at all. I am expecting this to be fixed with a service pack, or the classic "oh, that never worked correctly in (pevious version). You need (current version)."

Answer (score 0):

Does the mail server allow anonymous connections and/or does the user running the task have rights to send mail via the mail server?

It appears your mail server is requesting a user name from the task scheduler and closing the connection.

If you can't change the authentication mechanism on the mail server, you could look at tools like [blat](http://www.blat.net/) or use PowerShell ([Send-MailMessage](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849925.aspx)) to pass a message with explicit credentials.

Comment: The user running the task seems to have enough rights opening a socket to the mailserver. For the rest, it exchanges plain SMTP commands and data, which should be accepted by the mailserver. At least it is accepted when trying a manual send via port 25.

Comment: In your attempt to send manually, are you providing authentication?  Just saying that you can send mail via telnet doesn't answer my questions above to allow us to continue troubleshooting.